# how can I embed a foreign intent in my app?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I'm using [google's library](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/panorama/PanoramaClient.html) for showing 360° panoramas. If you are not familiar with the library all you need to now is that first the client is connected and after the input panorama is verified to be correct it returns an intent, which starts the activity that will display the panorama

In my app I have a tabhost and in a tab I want set this intent as content:

```
  TabHost.TabSpec spec3 = tabs.newTabSpec("tab3");
  Intent threeSixtyIntent = new Intent(MyApplication.getAppContext(),ThreeSixty.class);
  spec3.setContent(threeSixtyIntent);
```

But When I tried to set it with the intent from google's library I got a securityException, apparently because this intent regards another app. Is there any way around this?